# Android Null pointer exception in date formatting

Tags: android, android-listview, nullpointerexception, parse-platform

I am looking to recieve a date object from Parse.com database and then format it into a particular format and add it to a list view. This is my code :

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Trips");
       query.whereEqualTo("user", currentUser);
       query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> pobjects, ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(e==null)
            {
                Trips[] data = null;
                int i = 0;
                for(ParseObject po : pobjects)
                {
                    if(data==null)
                    {
                        data = new Trips[pobjects.size()];
                    }
                    Trips trip = new Trips(po.getString("to"), formatter.format(po.getString("start")) + " - " + formatter.format(po.getString("end")));
                }
                TripListAdapter mTripAdapter = new TripListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item_trip_list, data);
                mTripsList.setAdapter(mTripAdapter);

            }
        }
    });
```

I am getting a null pointer exception on this line

```
            Trips trip = new Trips(po.getString("to"), formatter.format(po.getString("start")) + " - " + formatter.format(po.getString("end")));
```

in the date formatter. start and end are two columns in my database, whose values are date objects which i am converting to string using simple formatter.
What is the mistake I am making ?
Thanks

Comment: Have you initialized `formatter` somewhere? If so, show how/where.

Comment: Yes. I have not included that part of the code here.

Comment: Break the line in different lines to find where the null is, or inspect with a debugger.

Comment: Yes I have done that. The NPE is in the formatter. But I can't figure out what the problem is exactly.

Comment: can you include the part of "formatter" in the question